# SVG.JS: How do I center text at a point?

Tags: svg.js

I'm using SVG.js, and I want to centre text at a point.
This works with normal svg using the 'dominant-baseline' or 'alignment-baseline' property, but SVG.js seems to completely ignore the property.

```
itemSVG.plain("centre me pls").move(100,100)
.font({'size':30,anchor:'
.attr({'pointer-events':'none',"dominant-baseline":'central'});
```

I've tried using dy to no avail. 
Thanks :)

Comment: It does not ignore it but your browser does. Baseline support is awful in all major Browsers!

Comment: 3: right - i'll just move it down by a bit then. Thanks for the note :)